# LINQ to SQL Query Error when using Joins with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query as

```
from elements in context.Catalog_Element
    join elementattributevalues in context.Catalog_ElementAttributeValue 
         on elements.ElementID equals elementattributevalues.ElementID
    join allowedsubcomponents in context.Catalog_AllowedSubComponents
         on new { AttributeValueID = elementattributevalues.AttributeValueID, 
                  ElementClassID = elements.ElementClassID }
         equals new { AttributeValueID = allowedsubcomponents.AttributeValueIDFilter, 
                  ElementClassID = allowedsubcomponents.ClassIDFilter }
    where allowedsubcomponents.ElementID == 
           new Guid("8c139311-f7cd-4961-a8bb-0d8dd923049e")
    select new
    {
        elements.ElementNumber,
        elements.Description
    })
```

This is showing me a syntax error as the type of one the expressions in the Join clause is incorrect.  Please help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid C# code that compiles at all. Please correct it. Also please explain what you are trying to do? What does Catalog_Element represent? What is ElementAttributeValues?

Comment: Corrected the code I am trying to get data three tables catalog_element,catalog_elementAttributevalue,& catalog_allowedsubcomponents. catalog_element is a table where as Elementattribute value is alias for catalog_elementAttributevalue.  I have checked for anonymous types and Data types  as well still the syntax at second join is showing me the error

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clearly telling you that your types do not match so you really need to confirm the types.

I would do this for each of the four fields (changing the table and the field respectively) to see what they types are reporting:

```
// look at these in debugger or write them to console
var myFirstType = context.Catalog_ElementAttributeValue
    .Take(1)
    .Select (x => x.AttributeValueID)
    .GetType()
    .ToString();

var mySecondType = .....
```

Also, you can quickly take a look at your join clause by forcing your data to strings just to see if it works:

```
on new 
{ 
    AttributeValueID = elementattributevalues.AttributeValueID.ToString(),  
    ElementClassID = elements.ElementClassID.ToString() 
} 
equals new 
{   
    AttributeValueID = allowedsubcomponents.AttributeValueIDFilter.ToString(),  
    ElementClassID = allowedsubcomponents.ClassIDFilter.ToString() 
}
```

Then try it with only AttributeValueID converted to strings and finally try it with only ElementClassID converted to strings. The one or ones that fail will tell you where your type problems are.

I suspect the problem actually has to do with a nullable type.